Volume integral over arbitrary triangle.
We have a function look like $z(x,y)=\sqrt{1 - x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2}$, where a and b are constants.
Need to compute the volume integral over some triangle with arbitrary coordinates in plane XY: $A(xA,yA), B(xB,yB), C(xC,yC)$. $A \neq B \neq C$.
